# Handsontable: How to sum rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handsontable

I get columns dynamically from the database, so I don't know how many columns I'll have, but the number of rows is fixed.

This is an example

```js
  var data = [
      ['', 'Tesla', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
      ['number of cars', -5, 5, 12, 13],
      ['price of a car', 10, -11, 14, 13],
    ['tax', 2, 15, -12, 30],
      ['Total price of all cars', 10, -11, 14, 13],
      ['price before tax', 2, 15, -12, 30],
      ['price after tax', 2, 15, -12, 30]
    ],
    container,
    hot1;
  
  function firstRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    td.style.color = 'green';
    td.style.background = '#CEC';
  }
  
  function negativeValueRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  
    // if row contains negative number
    if (parseInt(value, 10) < 0) {
      // add class "negative"
      td.className = 'make-me-red';
    }
  
    if (!value || value === '') {
      td.style.background = '#EEE';
    }
    else {
      if (value === 'Nissan') {
        td.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
      }
      td.style.background = '';
    }
  }
  // maps function to lookup string
  Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer('negativeValueRenderer', negativeValueRenderer);
  
  container = document.getElementById('example1');
  hot1 = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
    afterSelection: function (row, col, row2, col2) {
      var meta = this.getCellMeta(row2, col2);
  
      if (meta.readOnly) {
        this.updateSettings({fillHandle: false});
      }
      else {
        this.updateSettings({fillHandle: true});
      }
    },
    cells: function (row, col) {
      var cellProperties = {};
      var data = this.instance.getData();
  
      if (row === 0 || data[row] && data[row][col] === 'readOnly') {
        cellProperties.readOnly = true; // make cell read-only if it is first row or the text reads 'readOnly'
      }
      if (row === 0) {
        cellProperties.renderer = firstRowRenderer; // uses function directly
      }
      else {
        cellProperties.renderer = "negativeValueRenderer"; // uses lookup map
      }
  
      return cellProperties;
    }
  });
```

```css
.make-me-red {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@7.3.0/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@7.3.0/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<div id="example1" class="hot1 hot handsontable"></div>
```

I get the number of cars from the database. You define:

- The price of the car
- The tax per car

Total price of all cars should be total number of number of cars * price per car

price after tax should be price of a car + tax.

All I can do now is  `setDataAtCell` [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) , I want something like `setDataAtRow` and I don't want to specify the cell as an parameter.

Comment: I dont understand your problem. Can you elaborate a bit more please ? Do you want to make the sum for cells of each row (a total column) ? What is the problem with using `setDataAtCell` ? And also you jsfiddle link seems dead. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Hansontable Column Summary, you dont need to use setDataAtCell/setDataAtRow method.

https://handsontable.com/docs/7.3.0/demo-summary-calculations.html

```js
columnSummary: function() {
    // hotInstance(get total rows and total columns)
    let sumRow =  this.hot.countRows() - 1;
    let colSummaryArr = [];
    if(this.hot.countCols() > 0) {
        // sum would be for column 3 onwards
        for(let i = 3; i < this.hot.countCols(); i++) {
            colSummaryArr.push({
                destinationRow: sumRow - 1,
                destinationColumn: i,
                type: 'sum',
                ranges: [
                [0, this.hot.countRows() - 3]
                ],
            })
            // custom eg which calculates difference of sum row with certain value 
            colSummaryArr.push({
                type: 'custom',
                destinationRow: sumRow,
                destinationColumn: i,
                customFunction: function(endpoint) {
                    var hotInstance = this.hot;
                    function checkRange() {
                        let sum  = 0;
                        for(let i = 0; i < hotInstance.countRows()-2; i++) {
                            sum += hotInstance.getDataAtCell(i, endpoint.destinationColumn);
                        }
                        return sum;
                    }
                    return 8 - checkRange();
                }
            })
        }                                       
        return colSummaryArr;
    }
    else {
        return [];
    }
},
```